# Is there a way to copy constraint parameters of a component in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: java, android

I have a `View` in my `ConstraintLayout` which is positioned in XML. Then I want to change this view to another view on button click. I have the script to do it and it works OK, but the new `View` appears at the top of the screen and I need it to be in the **same position as the previous**. I've read Google Android documentation, but nothing I found seems to help me. Is the only way to do it is by using `ConstraintSet.connect()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by re-using the original view's `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` object:

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) viewToRemove.getLayoutParams();

    parent.removeView(viewToRemove);
    parent.addView(viewToAdd, params);
});
```

Note that this will give the same **width** and **height** as the old view as well, so you may have to explicitly set those if you need them to be different:

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = 
        (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) toRemove.getLayoutParams();

params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

Comment: I needed it to be of the same size anyways. And yeah, it worked just like I wanted it to.