# Copy properties from one view in constraint layout to another when it is hidden

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am beginner in using ConstraintLayout

I have a usecase, when a one TextView is gone in the constraint layout I want to place another TextView to exact same position as the now hidden TextView. 
In the xml it is easy, is there possibility to achieve the same programmatically?

Here is the layout xml before the changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/some_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="SOME TITLE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/stone"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/some_title"
            tools:text="I WILL BE HIDDEN" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:maxWidth="88dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:text="I WILL CHANGE THE POSITION"
            tools:textColor="@color/green" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

And here is how it should look after changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card_container"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/someTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="SOME TITLE"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/stone"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/someTitle"
            tools:text="I AM HIDDEN NOW" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/stone"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/someTitle"
            tools:text="I SHOULD REPLACED THE TEXTVIEW1 POSITION!"
            tools:textColor="@color/green" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

So, as you can see I just copied all of the positioning values from "textView1" to "textView2"(with some adjustments for "someTitle")
How can I do it programmatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617541/is-there-a-way-to-copy-constraint-parameters-of-a-component-in-constraintlayout

Comment: Yes, @RahulShukla is right. K. Os, why did you set a bounty for such an easy question? :)

Comment: Well it is pretty bad that I must create everything from scratch in this case, as there is no such API in android that will just simply copy all of the properties to another, so I would no need to do that all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came up with my own solution, as none of the other fully covered my usecase.
So I just introduced a barrier https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier to hold the bottom reference from the bottom `some_title` TextView to top of the others TextViews. In that case made adjustments in the layout xml:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card_container"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/someTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomAreaBarrier"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="SOME TITLE" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/bottomAreaBarrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="top"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView1,textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/stone"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="TEXTVIEW TO BE REPLACED SOMETIMES" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:maxWidth="88dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:text="I WILL CHANGE POSITION FOR TEXTVIEW1 SOMETIMES"
            tools:textColor="@color/green" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In that case, I can just simply change the Gravity of the `textView2` whenever should be the case:

```
  if (textView1.text.isEmpty()) {
      textView2.gravity = Gravity.START
   } else {
      textView2.gravity = Gravity.END
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

For this I would have 2 approaches, my first choice would be changing the `ConstraintSets` of the views am interested in like

```
 ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
    constraintSet.connect(textView2.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    constraintSet.connect(textView2.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Of course, this will not be easy.

My 2nd approach easier than option one would be to copy the `LayoutParams` of `TextView1` or view to be `GONE` then remove it from the layout and replace it with `TextView2` like this

```
  ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) textView1.getLayoutParams();

    constraintLayout.removeView(textView1);
    constraintLayout.removeView(textView2);
    constraintLayout.addView(textView2, params);
```

For both of these options to work you will need to alter your layout, remove any constraints that connect the views you want to manipulate with those that should remain on screen like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/someTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="SOME TITLE"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="I WILL BE HIDDEN"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/someTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:maxWidth="88dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:paddingTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="I WILL CHANGE THE POSITION"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And you will have you result. I got this with option 2

[image]

With option 2 you can create method that takes in 2 views, function that you can use to quickly play with the views

```
   private void changeReplaceViews(View viewToReplace, View viewToTakeOver){
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) viewToReplace.getLayoutParams();
    constraintLayout.removeView(viewToReplace);
    constraintLayout.removeView(viewToTakeOver);
    constraintLayout.addView(viewToTakeOver, params);   
}
```

Comment: Seems that won't work if this layout is inside the recycler view - your solution is not being applied for items that are not rendered on the screen yet. Same goes if I return to this screen after going back from another screen

Comment: @K.Os If the view is not in a recycler you need to call `view.requestLayout()` for it to be re-rendered with the new `params` for a recyclerview call `notifyDataSetChanged` also you could have specified in the question you wanted to display the item in a recycler, this was a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy, Android framework supports adding the view by code and xml both way. Check for the view's visibility with help of **`getVisibility()`** and **`isShown()`**. After determining the visibility state you can create a new view and attach it to the parent `ViewGroup` container. Consider the creation of `TextView` here,

```java
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_parent_container);
TextView mTextView = new TextView(this); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mParams.leftMargin = 50;
mParams.topMargin  = 50;
mTextView.setText("Hello!");
mTextView.setTextSize((float) 20);
mTextView.setPadding(20, 50, 20, 50);
mTextView.setLayoutParams(mParams);
mRelativeLayout.addView(tv[i]);
```

This is example creation of `TextView` and attached to the parent `RelativeLayout`. You can create desired view and attach to the parent container by the same way without worrying about the type of `ViewGroup`. Here in your case, If you need to attach the `View` to `ConstraintLayout`, You'll be needing the **`ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`** for that view.

If you want to copy/clone the existing view,

```
TextView existingTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.existing_tv);
TextView cloned = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
cloned.setText(existingTv.getText());
cloned.setLayoutParams(existingTv.getLayoutParams()); //override anything you want
```

Be patience while cloning view from ConstraintLayout. ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams cache its parameters, and is associated with the View you use it on, so you cannot simply pass one widget's LayoutParams to another.

You have to instead generate a new LayoutParams for your new View object, and copy the corresponding fields.

For example, if you have something like this,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Hello!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then you can do it as given below,

```java
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams mParam = 
                (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();

TextView clonedTextView = new TextView(this);

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

newParams.leftToLeft = mParam.leftToLeft;
newParams.topToTop = mParam.topToTop;
newParams.leftMargin = mParam.leftMargin;
newParams.topMargin = mParam.topMargin;

layout.addView(clonedTextView, -1, newParams);
```

This would put the second TextView exactly in the same position as the one defined in XML layout.

Comment: Is there no such api as simple copying all of the existing parameters from one text view to another? So that i don't want to just create everything again from scratch

Comment: Btw, I am using ConstraintLayout, nor does it matter, and coding in Kotlin :)

Comment: Btw2, please provide the concrete solution for my case and i will grant you the bounty reward, as I'm not sure if your solution will work in details

Comment: Please check the updated answer. If you are using kotlin, the Same approach should work for it with minor changes in example code. Hop it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for update, but will the "getLayoutParams" work for constraints in ConstraintLayout? As I was trying Im afraid it won't

Comment: The `getLayoutParams` methos will not work for constraint view group. There are several methods to achieve it. you can create default layout params using `generateDefaultLayoutParams()` and `generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p)`. You can find more detailes on this method here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout Have you tried getting LayoutParam of the TextView? and set it to cloned one? It should work.

Comment: @K.Os check the updated answer having your query resolution about how to copy it's LayoutParams and apply it to cloned view.